# Mapstruct and Sprinboot 3 native - Cannot find implementation

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

i have a strange problem with mapstruct and springboot 3, when i try to compile the native application.
I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for it.company.example.mapper.TestMapper at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75) ~[na:na] at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58) ~[na:na]

Is mapstruct working with springboot native? Thank you!

I've tryed a lot of modification, but i can't figure out what is the problem, maybe the mapstruct annotation processor is not working with native compilation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use:

```java
MyMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);
```

but annotate your mapper with: `@Mapper(componentModel = SPRING)`

then let spring inject mapper bean, it should work:

```java
private final RepositoryMapper mapper;
// write setter or constructor injector
```